# Java: How to get rid of only some numbers in a list?

Tags: java

I don't really know how to explain this but i can show. The goal i want to accomplish is that the first loop produces numbers 1,2,3,4,5. Then the second loop produces numbers 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9. I want this second loop to output the numbers 6,7,8,9. Then in the third loop it would output 10,11,12,13,14,15. Now how would I go by doing this?

```
                int horse= 5

        for (int w =1; w <= horse; w++)
        {
            System.out.println(w + " The first loop");
        }

        int test= horse + 4;

        for (int w =1; w <= test; w++)
        {
            System.out.println(w + " The second loop");

        }

        int try = test + 6;

        for (int w =1; w <= try; w++)
        {
            System.out.println(w + " The third loop");
        }
```

Comment: Pay ***very close*** attention to what you're setting your `w` variable to.

Comment: let me get this straight: you want to produce the numbers 1..15 with three loops instead of one?

Comment: @Kevin, he's probably just playing around and trying to teach himself the basics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't reinitialize your `w` variable back to 1 each time. You can do this simply by omitting it.

```
    int horse= 5;
    int w;
    //loop from 1 to 5
    for (w =1; w <= horse; w++)
    {
        System.out.println(w + " The first loop");
    }

    int test= horse + 4;
    //loop from 6 to 9
    //here the initial value of w is 6 from the previous loop
    for (; w <= test; w++)
    {
        System.out.println(w + " The second loop");

    }

    int try0 = test + 6;
    //loop from 10 to 15
    //here the initial value of w is 10 from the previous loop
    for (; w <= try0; w++)
    {
        System.out.println(w + " The third loop");
    }
```

Note that `try` is a reserved system keyword, so rename it to something like `try0`

Comment: This won't even compile... The variable `w` expires after the first `for()` block.

Comment: Too much Python. Thanks, fixed :)

Comment: Observed revision history.  I guess that I saw the new revision before the new revision was applied...hmm.

Answer (score 0):

This will do what you need ([see live example here](https://ideone.com/Cd6quc)):

```
// put the increments in an array instead of a scalar.
int[] loops = {5, 4, 6};
String[] names = {"first", "second", "third"};

for(int i = 0, sum = 0; i < loops.length; sum += loops[i++])
    for(int j = sum; j < sum + loops[i]; j++)
        System.out.println((j + 1) + " The " + names[i] + " loop");
```

---

**Output:**

```
1 The first loop
2 The first loop
3 The first loop
4 The first loop
5 The first loop
6 The second loop
7 The second loop
8 The second loop
9 The second loop
10 The third loop
11 The third loop
12 The third loop
13 The third loop
14 The third loop
15 The third loop
```